# 'Good stomach' or 'good digestion'

Tags: idioms

Are these two sentences interchangeable?

My question is whether 'I have a good stomach' is the same as 'I have a good digestion'.

There are many idioms relating to 'stomach', and I am afraid my sentence will be understood in a very different way.

http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/stomach

Answer (score 1):

> I have a good stomach.

means your stomach (the physical organ) is working properly.

> I have good digestion. (no article)

means your digestion (the process of consuming food to be broken down for nutrition) is good. It could be about your stomach, but could also be about the foods you eat (healthy food vs. junk food, for example).